# A Proof of a False Result: If $U$ is $T$-invariant, then so is $U^\perp$.

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, orthogonality, fake-proofs, trace

$\newcommand{\ab}[1]{\langle #1\rangle}\DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{trace}\newcommand{\mc}{\mathcal}$

I have a "proof" of the following wrong fact:

> Let $T$ be a linear operator on a finite dimensional complex inner product space. Let $U$ be a $T$-invariant subspace of $V$.
>   Then $U^\perp$ is also $T$-invariant.

(The proof is motivated from [this](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Invariant_Subspaces_of_Finite-Dimensional_Normal_Operators) page.)

We use the fact that writing $\ab{T, S}=\tr(TS^*)$ defines an inner product on the linear space $\mc L(V)$.
Let $p:V\to V$ denote the projection on $U$ with respect to $U^\perp$ and note that saying $U$ is invariant under $T$ is same as writing $(I-p)Tp=0$.
So to show that $U^\perp$ is invariant under $T$, we need to show that $S:=pT(I-p)=0$.
To do this, it suffices to show that $\tr(S S^*)=0$.
Since $p$ is is an orthogonal projection map, we have $p^*=p$.

Using $\tr(AB)=\tr(BA)$ for $A, B\in \mc L(V)$, we have

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\tr(SS^*) &=& \tr(pT(I-p)(I-p)T^*p)\\
&=& \tr(pT(I-p)^2T^*p)\\
&=& \tr(pT(I-p)T^*p)\\
&=& \tr((pT-pTp)T^*p)\\
&=& \tr(pTT^*p)-\tr(pTpT^*p)\\
&=& \tr(p^2TT^*)-\tr(p^3TT^*)\\
&=& \tr(pTT^*)-\tr(pTT^*) = 0
\end{array}
$$
And therefore we have our result.

*Where am I making a mistake?*

Comment: What is inner product on $V$ ? $(x,y)=\sum x_i \overline{y_i} $ ?

Comment: @HKLee The inner product on $V$ does not matter. The adjoints appearing above, like $T^*$ and $S^*$, depend on the chosen inner product.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that $pT\neq Tp$ in general, so the traces of $pTpT^*p$ and $p^2TT^*p$ need not be equal.

Consider the linear operator
$$
T
=
\begin{pmatrix}
2&1\\
0&2
\end{pmatrix}
$$
on $\mathbb C^2$.
Now $U=\{(x,0);x\in\mathbb C\}$ is $T$-invariant ($TU\subset U$) but its orthogonal complement $U^\perp=\{(0,y);y\in\mathbb C\}$ is not.

Simple calculations give
$$
p
=
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0\\
0&0
\end{pmatrix},
\quad
(I-p)Tp=0,
\quad
pT(1-p)
=
\begin{pmatrix}
0&1\\
0&0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Now the two traces are indeed different, as a calculation shows you.
In fact, the traces of $pTpT^*p$ and $p^2TT^*p$ are the square norms of $pTp$ and $pT$, respectively, and
$$
pTp
=
\begin{pmatrix}
2&0\\
0&0
\end{pmatrix},
\quad
pT
=
\begin{pmatrix}
2&1\\
0&0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Comment: So is it wrong to say that $\tr(AB)=\tr(BA)$?

Comment: @caffeinemachine that's completely right but it doesn't imply tr(ABCD) = tr(ACBD) -- it only shows that the trace of a big product of operators is invariant under cyclic permutations of the product. This is actually the second most upvoted "common false belief" on the page http://mathoverflow.net/questions/23478/examples-of-common-false-beliefs-in-mathematics

Comment: @caffeinemachine, the trace is invariant under *cyclic* permutations of the matrices, not under *all* of them.

Comment: @Joonas Oh man! I have been sitting on this for hours! Thanks!

Comment: @caffeinemachine, I'm glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 1):

If $T$ is triangular, and $p(v=\sum_i v_i e_i)=v_1e_1,\ v_i\in \mathbb{C}$, then $$ Tpe_n=0,\ pTe_n= T_{1n} \neq 0 $$

So $$pT\neq Tp$$

In your calculation, second equality in the bottom is wrong.